# How do you select which projects gets loaded in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have an extra project getting loaded besides Project.iOS and Project.Android. How do take this out of the build? When I try to build my project, I see an external library, along with Project.iOS and Project.Android. How do I take this external library out?

Comment: Just remove it from your solution.  But that is most likely your shared Forms library and should not be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution I was looking for is to "Unload" project preventing it from being loaded in your starter projects which should only be .iOS and .Android.